# How is digital currency different from that of an e-wallet?

Tags: money-transfer, transfer, virtual-currency

To quote from the newspaper,

> Unlike e-wallet Digital currency does not involve a third party.

A detailed explanation to this will be most certainly welcome. What is really being referred to here as the "third party"? Also it says that unlike e-wallets digital currency does not really require internet connectivity. A detailed explanation to this is most welcome.

For context, here is the full quote

> Unlike an e-wallet such as Paytm in India, or Alipay or WeChat Pay, which are the two dominant apps in China, the Digital RMB does not involve a third party. Unlike e-wallets, the digital currency does not require Internet connectivity. The payment is made through Near-field Communication (NFC) technology

Comment: Can you include a larger quote, or a link to the article?

Comment: https://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/technology/the-hindu-explains-how-does-chinas-digital-currency-work/article34234504.ece

Comment: Unfortunately that article is behind a paywall. Could you add some additional context to the body of your question? Does the article give examples of what it considers an "e-wallet" and what is considers "digital currency"?

Comment: @glibdud Unlike an e-wallet such as Paytm in India, or Alipay or WeChat Pay, which are the two dominant apps in China, the Digital RMB does not involve a third party.

Unlike e-wallets, the digital currency does not require Internet connectivity. The payment is made through Near-field Communication (NFC) technology.

Comment: Perfect. Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @glibdud I have already added the quote.Can you explain what it means?

Comment: I can't, but someone here probably can. They'll need the full quote though, not just the shortened version that's still in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use any electronic wallet, there is a *central processor* inbolved - whoever provides the eWallet. You cannot simply pay your buddy that is standing next to you without the payment going through some central place where the transaction is recorded, together with the balance you each have afterwards.

For digital currency, the transfer can happen between the two of you, *without* anybody else in the world, similar to handing over a dollar bill or a chicken or a pebble. It is - *unfalsifiably* - recorded in both your devices that the money was transferred, and how much you each have afterwards.
The guaranteed verification is the key point; otherwise everybody could just fiddle with the files on his device at home, and add some money to his wallet with a binary editor.

Comment: How would the money be transferred if there is no internet connectivity?

Comment: It's a matter how you are setting your tools up. You can share a wireless network (with no internet connection), use bluetooth between the devices, or connect them with a cable, as you like.

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal although digital currency can be transferred without an internet connection (it can be transferred just like a file, on USB stick or even better: physically printed out, eventually it will need to go to the internet for final settlement), but that is not what Aganju was referring to. Digital currency does not require financial intermediaries like banks or brokers, but there will still be your internet provider (ISPs). The ISP isn't determining whether you can transact to your friend or not, and neither is any bank/broker/corporation. Thats what they mean by no central processor.